# react-native command not found in mac os

Tags: react-native

I have tried everything, but still not able to create react native app in my **mac os**

I have reinstall every step.

```
CLI installed successfully
/Users/prashantrana/.npm-global/bin/react-native -> /Users/prashantrana/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js
```

> -bash: react-native command not found

I expected that app should be created but command is not working at all

Comment: Did you follow all the steps given on react-native getting-stated documentation? https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started

Answer (score 0):

install React native globaly

```
npm i react-native-cli -g
```

Comment: Yes i have followed all the steps from documentation